# Tizen heart rate monitor rRInterval

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

In the Tizen Heart Rate Monitor (`HumanActivityHRMData`), is the value `rRInterval` the time of **the most recent interval** (and updated every heartbeat), or **is it a rolling average** of the last several heartbeats?

All the [documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.wearable.web.device.apireference/tizen/humanactivitymonitor.html#HumanActivityHRMData) says is:

> readonly long rRInterval
>
> Peak-to-peak interval in millisecond(s).

I'm trying to develop an app that needs a lot of precision in pulse detection, and a rolling average isn't precise enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about `HumanActivityHRMData` I'm assuming you are trying the *Tizen 2.3* version.

I have tested HRM on *2.2.1.x* (which is running Gear S) and the `rRInterval` (`MotionHRMInfo`) data has appeared on every beat, so I think it's the **most recent interval**.

This should be the same on the newer version, but there is no hardware to test it for now.